# Discovering Protractor / jasmine tests in Test explorer of Visual studio?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

I have an application written in angular and i have developed my app with angular-cli.
I have unit tests written using jasmine and E2E tests in protractor.

1. Is there a way i can discover my tests in Test explorer of Visual studio?
2. Is there a way i can associate the unit tests and protractor tests with test cases / work item in visual studio?

This is needed for generating test reports and to trace back the unit tests and E2E tests to the backlog items/ requirements in VSTS.

Additional info:
I have added my protractor tests in nodejs project.
The unit test are part of the angular application created with angular-cli.

I am using Visual studio 2017. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is just IDE tool. You can use any tool You want to make your coding experience better.

Depends in which language is written Your code, but for the node.js and angular you will need good JavaScript IDE.

The best tool that I have used for JavaScript is WebStorm of JetBrains, if you want free You should use Atom or Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Any suggestions for my second question: Is there a way i can associate the unit tests and protractor tests with test cases / work item in visual studio / VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

I will plus WebStorm as well. The big advantage they provide is Test runner window where you can visually see which tests failed/passed, easily navigate to the line of fail. All can be configured via GUI. They have predefined config for Protractor, Karma, etc

Visual Studio Code is very clean and fast but it misses some GUI tools. You can configure anything but you will have to do it from command line. It is free though.

Comment: Thanks! any help regarding my second question: Is there a way i can associate the unit tests and protractor tests with test cases / work item in visual studio / VSTS?

Comment: @user2439903 ,any finding on second question you asked , i am stuck with the same issue?